# Rails using hash in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning rails 4 and i am bit confused in some notation in the tutorial i am following. I am following Lynda Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training.

I have a simple controller with crud actions. In New action i am assing the instance variable the parameter as this (with curly braces)

```
@subject = Subject.new({:name=>'default'})
```

But in Create actions I am doing this:

```
Subject.new(params[:subject])
redirect_to(:action=>'index')
```

Shouldn't this `params[:subject]` and `:action=>'index'` should also be inside the curly braces?

How can i know when to use curly braces and not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params[:subject]` will most probably return a value like

```
{:attr1 => 'value1', :attr2 => 'value2'}
```

Enclosing this in curly braces will result in

```
{{:attr1 => 'value1', :attr2 => 'value2'}} # Not a valid Hash/Syntax
```

But, `render({:action => 'index'})` is same as without the curly braces. Ruby is intelligent enough to identify that it is a `Hash` without the curlies.

It is a common scenario to have a Hash as the last argument to a method.

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2, options={})
 ..
```

In this case, it is sometimes prefered to drop the `{}` as it could te mistaken for a block

```
my_method 1, 2, :opt1 => 'val1'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Strong Params**

Something to add to `Santosh`'s answer - you really need to consider the [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) method when creating new ActiveRecord objects (if you want to save them):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def new 
       @model = Model.new
   end

   def create
       @model = Model.new(model_params)
   end

   private

   def model_params
       params.require(:model).permit(:attributes, :for, :model)
   end
end
```

--

**Options**

In terms of your `redirect_to`, I think Santosh covered the bases very well; however, you may wish to use just a `symbol` to denote loading an action:

```
redirect_to :index
```

By default, Rails will use the same controller you're on, allowing you to point to various actions within it.

--

**Update**

For `strong_params`, you have to remember what this is doing exactly.

Strong Params is just a method which allows you to send certain parameters to the model. This means if someone tries to mass-assign, it won't pass the un-permitted params through.

When you mention that I'm calling the `model` twice - I'm only calling it for different actions. The `new` action is there to create a new instance of the `ActiveRecord object`, the `create` action is there to save that instance (you have to recreate it with the params from your form)

You'll want to [read up on `strong params` here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

Comment: thank you very much for this.. i am bit lost in permitting the attributes for mass assignment. There in your code you are requiring the same model for the controller and again later on inside permit you are again referring to the same model. why is that?

Comment: its very confusing syntax and hard to get by

Comment: You mean the `storng_params` syntax?